# How to get the iOS Camera suggest my app when snapping a QR code

Tags: ios, swift, qr-code, bitcoin, ios-camera

I want the Camera App that comes with an iPhone to recommend a QR code be opened up in my app. My first question is, if two or more apps register the same universal link, which app gets suggested.

For instance I removed one app that kept on being recommended. Then suddenly another app starts getting recommended. How does a user or developer control this.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Apple's guide for implementing Universal Links](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/inter-process_communication/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content). In short, your website must upload a JSON file at a specific location that tells iOS which apps can be associated with the website domain. [Here is an example file](https://www.nbc.com/apple-app-site-association) used by the NBC app.

Comment: I have created all that. but I think I am missing some step. I want my app to be suggested when the camera reads a QR code for "bitcoin:asdfasdfasdf"

Comment: and there is some sort of "prioritizing" of suggestion. I have been looking for docs on that.